# Check date is today's date or yesterday's date

Tags: php, date

I want to insert data into table when selected date is *Current Date* or *Yesterday's Date.*

*html code:*

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="reportdate" class="gui-input" placeholder="Select Date" required="Select date" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>">
```

*php code:*

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $report_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['reportdate']));
    $check_date=date('d',strtotime($_POST['reportdate']));

    if($check_date!=date('d') or $check_date!=date('d')-1){

        echo "<h2>You can only submit dcr of current date or yesterday.</h2>";
     }
     else{

     $client=$_POST['CLIENT_NAME'];
     //$cars_string = implode(', ', $_POST['cars']);
     $productname_string=implode(', ',$_POST['productname']);
     $remarks=$_POST['remark'];

     $sql="insert into d_c_r    (bm,date_time,client,promoted_product,remark) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."','$report_date',$client,'$productname_string','$remarks')";

     $res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it doesn't go in else part.

Comment: can you show us the output of `var_dump($report_date);` and `var_dump($check_date);`? add them before `if` condition and check and tell.

Comment: @AlivetoDie output of var_dump($report_date); Notice: Undefined variable: report_date in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pharmaerp\bm\daily_reporting.php on line 192
NULL

Comment: that is the issue brother. you are not getting any data from form. show your form code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Working Code Updated:**

**Working Demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fxh8-gnkw**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" name="myform">

<input type="date" id="datepicker1" name="reportdate" class="gui-input" placeholder="Select Date" required="Select date" value="">

<button type="submit" name="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['reportdate'])){

      $today_date  = date('d-m-Y'); // you get current date
      $date_tday = new DateTime($today_date);
      $date_tday->modify('-1 day');
      $get_yesterday_date_from_current = $date_tday->format('d-m-Y'); // you get Yesterday date that from current date


      $reportdate = $_POST['reportdate']; // you get report date that user is selected
      $report_date_format = new DateTime($reportdate);
      echo $report_date = $report_date_format->format('d-m-Y'); //you get report date that user is selected in d-m-Y

      /*
     $date = new DateTime($report_date);
     $date->modify('-1 day');
     echo $get_yesterday_date = $date->format('d-m-Y'); // you get Yesterday date that user is selected
      */

    if($report_date !== $today_date && $report_date !== $get_yesterday_date_from_current){

        echo "<h2>You can only submit dcr of current Date or Yesterday.</h2>";
     }
     else{

     echo "Inser Your Data OR What You WAnt To Do HERE";

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: it still goes in if part

Comment: @shubhamshah You Want to compare with which date ?? today or selected reported date

Comment: if selected date is today's date or yesterday's date then i want to insert data

Comment: ok instead of `var_dump($report_date);` do `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST);die;` just after `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` and then repost your form and show the output of it.

Comment: @shubhamshah Check Updated Ans

Comment: @Hackit :  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (14/10/2017) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pharmaerp\bm\daily_reporting.php:198
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Pharmaerp\bm\daily_reporting.php(198): DateTime->__construct('14/10/2017')
#1 {main}
  thrown on line 198

Comment: @shubhamshah i am Updated My Working Code Just Create One php File and Take an demo of it

Comment: @shubhamshah Check The Demo Link For :)

Comment: @Hackit date field is like 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 in database, i selected today's date.

Comment: what is your input type ?

Comment: @shubhamshah Check it Again You Did Something is Wrong ..or You can Just Give Me you Fiddle Link With Your Code !!